# Can I use TypeOrm's FindOperators inside a base class without getting bad SQL Unknown column '_type' in 'where clause'

Tags: sql, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to write a base class for CRUD operations for `"typeorm": "~0.2.45"` under `"@nestjs/typeorm": "~8.0.3"` using `node v14.19.3`.

The base class looks like this:

```
export class CrudService<T> {
    protected repository: Repository<T>;

    constructor(repository: Repository<T>) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    ...
    // Minimized code example
    async find() {
        return this.repository.find({
            where: {
                created: Between("2022-06-21T14:18:00.000Z", "2022-06-21T14:19:00.000Z")
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This generates the following SQL query (which is wrong), it seems to use the `Between()` object as a literal equality comparison.

```
query failed: SELECT ... FROM `carts` `CartEntity` WHERE `CartEntity`.`created` = ?
-- PARAMETERS: {
    "_type":"between",
    "_value":[
        "2022-06-21T14:18:00.000Z",
        "2022-06-21T14:19:00.000Z"
    ],
    "_useParameter":true,
    "_multipleParameters":true
}
```

If I implement the same code inside the `CartsEntity` service like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CartsService extends CrudService<CartEntity> {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(CartsRepository) repository: CartsRepository
    ) {
        super(repository);
    }
    ...
    async find() {
        return this.repository.find({
            where: {
                created: Between("2022-06-21T14:18:00.000Z", "2022-06-21T14:19:00.000Z")
            }
        });
    }
```

It works fine and retrieves the data with valid SQL using `BETWEEN` on MySql.

I am wondering what is wrong here since I am using the same instance of `repository` in both code examples. I tried looking at the TypeOrm FindOperator logic but could not pinpoint it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem is a difference in the typeorm npm versions I was using.

The CrudEntity described above is inside a private npm using typeorm 0.2.45 as are my microservices extending CrudEntity like the CartEntity above.

Since @nestjs/typeorm is tagged to typeorm 0.2.34 the type was not the same for FindOperator and thus returned as an object condition instead of a FindOperator generating the proper BETWEEN SQL statement.

Basically, make sure all typeorm versions are the same across all your projects sharing code.